# Is it possible to convert .avi file into rosbag file in ROS_KINETIC_KAME

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not understanding how to run a video using ros_kinetic_kame.
Please share me a video or complete process with all required packages that how to convert a .avi file into rosbag format.

---

Edit: This is my error I found :

```
$  roslaunch video_stream_opencv camera.launch video_stream_provider:="/home/test/Desktop/Prj/output.avi"
... logging to /home/test/.ros/log/98df6008-40c1-11e9-9e42-c81f6622f107/roslaunch-DH1CT5Z1-14580.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://DH1CT5Z1:34887/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/camera_stream/buffer_queue_size: 100
 * /camera/camera_stream/camera_info_url: 
 * /camera/camera_stream/camera_name: camera
 * /camera/camera_stream/flip_horizontal: False
 * /camera/camera_stream/flip_vertical: False
 * /camera/camera_stream/fps: 30.0
 * /camera/camera_stream/frame_id: camera
 * /camera/camera_stream/height: 0
 * /camera/camera_stream/loop_videofile: False
 * /camera/camera_stream/set_camera_fps: 30.0
 * /camera/camera_stream/video_stream_provider: /home/test/Deskto...
 * /camera/camera_stream/width: 0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /camera/
    camera_stream (video_stream_opencv/video_stream)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[camera/camera_stream-1]: started with pid [14597]
[ INFO] [1551955599.176597852]: Resource video_stream_provider: /home/test/Desktop/Prj/output.avi
[ INFO] [1551955599.176662227]: Getting video from provider: /home/test/Desktop/Prj/output.avi
[ INFO] [1551955599.179496159]: Video stream provider type detected: videofile
[ INFO] [1551955599.180594786]: Camera name: camera
[ INFO] [1551955599.181613177]: Setting camera FPS to: 30
[ INFO] [1551955599.181655102]: Camera reports FPS: 20
[ INFO] [1551955599.182527461]: Setting buffer size for capturing frames to: 100
[ INFO] [1551955599.183486775]: Throttling to fps: 30
[ INFO] [1551955599.184338937]: Publishing with frame_id: camera
[ INFO] [1551955599.185229180]: Provided camera_info_url: ''
[ INFO] [1551955599.186110557]: Flip horizontal image is: false
[ INFO] [1551955599.187001087]: Flip vertical image is: false
[ INFO] [1551955599.191553137]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1551955599.191696665]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/test/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1551955599.191759949]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/test/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1551955599.191787319]: Camera calibration file /home/test/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1551955599.191810010]: Opened the stream, starting to publish.
[camera/camera_stream-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/test/.ros/log/98df6008-40c1-11e9-9e42-c81f6622f107/camera-camera_stream-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317557/is-it-possible-to-convert-.avi-file-into-rosbag-file-in-ros_kinetic_kame/) by [SUBHASH](https://answers.ros.org/users/40114/subhash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-03-05**:
Yes, it is possible. Can you please tell us what have you tried and what didn't work exactly. As a start you can use [video_stream_opencv](http://wiki.ros.org/video_stream_opencv), [video_player](http://wiki.ros.org/video_player) is outdated.

**Comment by [SUBHASH](https://answers.ros.org/users/40114/subhash/) on 2019-03-07**:
How to get the video_stream_opencv
I have tries to get its packages but all I find the error for broken packages only

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-03-07**:
I've posted an answer for your first question that should work once the package is installed correctly. Can you please share the dependency errors that you've got to help you solve them.

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-03-07**:
did you use `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-video-stream-opencv` to install the package or install it from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've used video_stream_opencv once with ROS indigo,

Installed it with `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-video-stream-opencv`

And run it on an .avi video as follows:

```
#check if the input video is fine:
$ rosrun video_stream_opencv test_video_resource.py path_to_your_video/your_video.avi
#run it:
$ roslaunch video_stream_opencv camera.launch video_stream_provider:="path_to_your_video/your_video.avi"
```

The output topic is `/camera/image_raw`, note that you may need to adjust some parameters if needed (fps, frame_id...)

Once you have your topic ready you can record a bag of your video data directly with `rosbag record`

If your need is images published to a ROS topic, we are already there!

But if you just need the bag file and want a more direct conversion you may make use of  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432870/ros-convert-video-file-to-bag) and [this question's answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/11537/creating-a-bag-file-out-of-a-image-sequence/).

---

Originally posted by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) with karma: 188 on 2019-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SUBHASH](https://answers.ros.org/users/40114/subhash/) on 2019-03-07**:
After executing
$ rosrun video_stream_opencv  test_video_resource.py home/Desktop/Prj/output.avi
Error:
Trying to open resource: home/Desktop/Prj/output.avi
Error opening resource: home/Desktop/Prj/output.avi
Maybe opencv VideoCapture can't open it

**Comment by [SUBHASH](https://answers.ros.org/users/40114/subhash/) on 2019-03-07**:
Please tell me the process to execute this code with ROS.
Does it need video_stream_opencv?

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-03-07**:
Check the path to your video file again, I think that the user name is missing, it should be something like  `/home/user_name/Desktop/...`

**Comment by [SUBHASH](https://answers.ros.org/users/40114/subhash/) on 2019-03-07**:
$ roslaunch video_stream_opencv camera.launch video_stream_provider:="path_to_your_video/your_video.avi"
To launch this command roscore opened in another tab is required?

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-03-07**:
It should run `roscore` automatically... Maybe, I'm not sure in this case. Did it work only when having a running `roscore`?

**Comment by [SUBHASH](https://answers.ros.org/users/40114/subhash/) on 2019-03-07**:
I got this error:
$ roslaunch video_stream_opencv camera.launch video_stream_provider:="/hometest/Desktop/Prj/output.avi"
... logging to /home/test/.ros/log/98df6008-40c1-11e9-9e42-c81f6622f107/roslaunch-DH1CT5Z1-14432.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
goto next commen

**Comment by [SUBHASH](https://answers.ros.org/users/40114/subhash/) on 2019-03-07**:
This worked properly:
rosrun video_stream_opencv test_video_resource.py path_to_your_video/your_video.avi
Now I want to convert my .avi file to .bag file
How to do that?
$ roslaunch video_stream_opencv camera.launch video_stream_provider:="path_to_your_video/your_video.avi"
above command gave me err

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-03-07**:
what kind of error, can you post it here?

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-03-07**:
This is not an error, it means that everything is working fine :). Can you tell me if you are able to visualize your video frames when running `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw` in a new terminal just after running the previous command.

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-03-07**:
Sorry I've just seen your answer containing the output messages. don't add them as answer you can edit your question to add them.
did it say at some point `[ERROR]... Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...`
did you try running `roscore` first then `camera.launch` ?

**Comment by [SUBHASH](https://answers.ros.org/users/40114/subhash/) on 2019-03-07**:
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw
This worked I can see my video but now how to convert it into .bag format?

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-03-07**:
great! you can use [rosbag record](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#record) for that as mentioned in my answer.

**Comment by [SUBHASH](https://answers.ros.org/users/40114/subhash/) on 2019-03-07**:
I got this error while recording on tab of $ roslaunch video_stream_opencv camera.launch video_stream_provider:="/home/test/Desktop/Prj/output.avi" this command:
[ERROR] [1551958949.419922197]: Compressed Depth Image Transport - Compression requires single-channel 32bit-floating point or 16bit raw depth images (input format is: bgr8).
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (key_ != -1 && "Can't fetch data from terminated TLS container.") in getData, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/system.cpp, line 1532
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

**Comment by [SUBHASH](https://answers.ros.org/users/40114/subhash/) on 2019-03-07**:
But .bag file also created.
Now how to see whether recorded video is the same or not?

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-03-07**:
`rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw` and `rosbag play your_bag.bag`